# Refreshing captcha reloads the whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm new to JSON and jqueries. 
I created a captcha as below in cshtml file

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3"></div>
<iframe id="CaptchaIfram" src="@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage")" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<div>
     <div class="span3"></div>
     <input id="RefreshCaptcha" type="submit" onclick="captcha()" value="Refresh" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function captcha()
{
    document.getElementById("CaptchaIfram").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
</script>

in Controller:
public Captcha ShowCaptchaImage(int width, int height, int totalcharacters)
{
     return new Captcha(width, height, totalcharacters);
}
```

Its working fine and if I click on refresh button, whole page getting refreshed as I'm using Url.Action method.
To avoid this, I used JSON as below. But image is not getting displayed.
Can anybody let me know where I need to correct.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3"></div>
<iframe id="CaptchaIfram" onload="showCaptcha()" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <input id="RefreshCaptcha" type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick="showCaptcha()" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
</div>            

<script type="text/javascript">
function showCaptcha()
{
    var url = "/ESignature/ShowCaptchaImage";
    var target = '#CaptchaIfram';
    $.getJSON(url, { width: 200, height: 35, totalcharacters: 5 }, function (data) {
    document.getElementById("CaptchaIfram").src = data;
    });
}
</script>
public JsonResult ShowCaptchaImage(int width, int height, int totalcharacters)
{
    return Json(new Captcha(width, height, totalcharacters), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the type of refresh button to client side button as below. It didn't refresh the whole page.

No Json functions are required. (second code block in my question)